# Disable left to right scrolling UIWebView iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and I'm loading an HTML string I scrape from a website. This html contains a table that I load an it looks fine, but the table doesn't fit to the screen when in portrait orientation on the iPhone. The table fits excellent on when in landscape orientations. What my question is, how can I set the UIWebView to not scroll left to right when I am in Landscape Orientation. The table fits well in that orientation, but there is white space after the table and the iPhone wants to show it, but it doesn't need too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=480, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Of course, make sure that your HTML actually fits the screen.

Comment: How can I insert this in the `<head>` of the HTML string?

Comment: You mention you load a HTML string loaded from a website. I'd assume that you can simply replace the `</head>` tag with `<themetatag></head>` or something.